# php and mysql : database not retriving data inside print

Tags: php, mysql

In the below code **inside print i have $ fullname and $email**

I don't know why its not retriving from database

can any one help me:

```
<?php
//Connect to the database through our include 
include_once "database.php";
// Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobseeker_members WHERE id='$userid'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$fullname = $row["fullname"];
$country = $row["country"];
$state = $row["state"];
$city = $row["city"];
$dob = $row["dob"];
$contact=$row["contact"];
$qualific=$row["qualification"];
$job1=$row["jobint1"];
$job2=$row["jobint2"];
$job3=$row["jobint3"];  
}

      print"
       <br /><br /><br /><h4>OK $fullname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
        We just sent an Activation link to: $email<br /><br />
      <h2>Last Step to verify your email identity :</h2><br /><br />
        <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
        Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
      ?>
```

Comment: `$email` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: What's the value of `$userid`. Is there any rows for that id?

Comment: @Shamil $fullname is defined why fullname is not displaying

Comment: if you echo your query. what you get ? if query does not fetch records than while loop will not run, therefore $fullname and $email will not be populated

Comment: an out of loop suggestion....DO NOT USE `mysql_` any more....its insecure, go for `mysqli_` or `PDO`...

Answer (score 1):

can you try:

```
var_dump($result); //should tell you if the result contains anything (and if so, what)
```

Also:

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result); // should tell you the number of rows
```

If you get 0 from num rows, your SQL is most likely at fault.
If you get a number and only the print does not work, check if there actually is a value in $fullname.

I recommend that you rewrite your code to use Mysqli with prepared statements.